# Python - "subprocess.popen" getting no output from java application and instead only stops at "object at 0x02AXXX" --

Tags: java, python

I am trying to run a simple hello world java programme from python but it somehow stops at

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x02A5FC10>
>>>   no out put here ??
```

i also tried

```
>>> output = p.communicate() 
error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    output = p1.communicate()
  File "C:\Users\Chamarthy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1055, in communicate
    stdout = self.stdout.read()
ValueError: read of closed file
```

```html
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Users\\Chamarthy\\Desktop\\work\\arrayproject\\src\\arrayproject\\hello.Main", "MyClass"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
>>> print (p)
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x02A5FC10>
>>>
```

```html
package arrayproject;

public class hello {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Hello World!" + args[0]);
     } 
}
```

Comment: In the python parent script... are you sure you didn't get an error message on the screen with `Popen`? You passed windows an invalid executable and you didn't redirect `stderr`, an error is expected. Your `p.communicate()` should work. The error you got suggests that you called it twice...  that's the normal error you get if you call `communicate` a second time.

Comment: thanks for sugession , i am new to python. I got your second point , however still i am confused wether the os.path that i have specified here is correct path. As i have this java class hello in project explorer in eclipse and therefore i have specified the path to the workspace folder. Also i just want to see helloworld string displayed as output in python IDLE upon execution of command print(p). What am i doing wrong?? .I have managed to get this output so far which i guess is os execution error
>>> p.communicate()
(b'', None)
>>>